# How do I use jQuery in Rails 6.0.3.3?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

running Rails 6.0.3.3 and can't get jQuery to work.

Here's packs/application.js

```
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")
```

And in my view I have something like this:

```
<head>
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %> 
</head>

 <div id="pop">
   TEST
 </div>
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $('#pop').hide(); 
      });
 </script>
```

And so when my page loads I would expect the #pop div that says 'TEST' to NOT show. It seems as if this set up is just not working. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Rails 6 doesn't include JQuery by default. It looks like you didn't install it.

Here's a [link](https://www.botreetechnologies.com/blog/introducing-jquery-in-rails-6-using-webpacker) that shows how does Webpack works and how to install JQuery with Rails 6.

But if just want to install JQuery, here is how to do it:

Run `yarn add jquery` in your project.

Be sure to check if Jquery has been successfully installed by checking your `package.json` and `yarn.json` where the JQuery package should be visible.

Then add this snippet in your `environment.js`:

```js
environment.plugins.prepend('Provide',
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery/src/jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery/src/jquery'
  })
)
```

Your `environment.js` should then look like this:

```js
const { environment } = require("@rails/webpacker");
const webpack = require("webpack");

environment.plugins.append(
  "Provide",
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: "jquery/src/jquery",
    jQuery: "jquery/src/jquery",
  })
);

module.exports = environment;
```

Now simply add `require('jquery')` in your `application.js`.

`application.js` file:

```js
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")
require("jquery")
```

Comment: THank you. Trying this now. Running into an issue, where is this environment.js file you speak of?

Comment: THank you. Trying this now. I was able to paste that code into the environment.js and the application.js files, but it still isn't working :( any other thoughts?

Comment: Did you install jquery by running `yarn add jquery` ? Also do check in the console of the developement tools if you get any error message.

Comment: @WesCreations Did you get jQuery working? And where is the environment.js file?  I'm trying to get it to work myself: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75178270/how-do-i-add-jquery-to-mastodon-4-02-using-rails-6-and-webpacker-4