# How do I add jQuery to Mastodon 4.02 (using Rails 6 and Webpacker 4)?

Tags: jquery, reactjs, ruby-on-rails, webpack, mastodon

I'm following this question from 2020 [How do I use jQuery in Rails 6.0.3.3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64187192/how-do-i-use-jquery-in-rails-6-0-3-3) , but I'm not able to add jQuery to Rails 6 and Webpacker 4 in Mastodon 4.02 https://github.com/mastodon/mastodon However, I am able to add a custom.js file to load my jQuery function; it's the main jQuery library that isn't loading.

---

**Edit 1/27/23**

**Takeaways:**

**•** Why don't I have an environment.js file? Is this because of Webpacker 4?

**•** I tried the two other approaches below to load the jQuery library directly in `app/views/layouts/application.html.haml`, but both throw the generic Mastodon error page and their are no errors using `journalctl -u mastodon-web`. Neither of these work:

`= javascript_pack_tag 'jquery-min'` to load `app/javascript/packs/jquery-min.js` (where jquery-min.js is the jQuery library).

`= javascript_include_tag "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.6.min.js"`

---

**Original question:**

In `Mastodon:~/live$` I run `yarn add jquery` and that returns:

```
yarn add v1.22.19
[1/6] Validating package.json...
[2/6] Resolving packages...
[3/6] Fetching packages...
[4/6] Linking dependencies...
warning Workspaces can only be enabled in private projects.
[5/6] Building fresh packages...
[6/6] Cleaning modules...
warning Workspaces can only be enabled in private projects.
success Saved 1 new dependency.
info Direct dependencies
└─ jquery@3.6.3
info All dependencies
└─ jquery@3.6.3
Done in 24.18s.
```

I see that `jQuery` has been added to `package.json` and `yarn.lock`.

I added `require('jquery')` to app/javascript/packs/application.js:

```
import './public-path';
import loadPolyfills from '../mastodon/load_polyfills';
import { start } from '../mastodon/common';

start();

loadPolyfills().then(async () => {
  const { default: main } = await import('mastodon/main');

  return main();
}).catch(e => {
  console.error(e);
});

require('jquery')
require('packs/custom') // custom.js file I added
```

**But I don't have an environment.js file in the Mastodon site files, and the non-existent environment.js file should include this, as referenced in the linked question:**

```
const { environment } = require("@rails/webpacker");
const webpack = require("webpack");

environment.plugins.append(
  "Provide",
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: "jquery/src/jquery",
    jQuery: "jquery/src/jquery",
  })
);

module.exports = environment;
```

I run

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake tmp:cache:clear
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails assets:generate_static_pages
```

And then

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails assets:precompile
```

and that outputs this:

```
yarn install v1.22.19
[1/6] Validating package.json...
[2/6] Resolving packages...
[3/6] Fetching packages...
[4/6] Linking dependencies...
warning Workspaces can only be enabled in private projects.
[5/6] Building fresh packages...
[6/6] Cleaning modules...
Done in 18.17s.
Everything's up-to-date. Nothing to do
```

I exit from the root account and run

`systemctl restart mastodon-*`

I test for jQuery in the console and it's not loading:

[image]

But, the `packs/custom.js` file is loading, as it contains

```
console.log("custom js is loaded");
```

and I see `custom js is loaded` in the console.

**Any ideas? Why is jQuery not loading?**

1. Where is the environment.js file file?
2. Is the notice `warning Workspaces can only be enabled in private projects` a serious error?
3. I have run `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails assets:clobber` to clear Webpacker and that doesn't help with the missing jQuery library.

---

**Edit 1/25/23:**

As per mechnicov's answer, this is the shared.js file in /config/webpack/, but no luck when adding

`new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ $: "jquery", jQuery: "jquery" })`

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const { basename, dirname, join, relative, resolve } = require('path');
const { sync } = require('glob');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const AssetsManifestPlugin = require('webpack-assets-manifest');
const extname = require('path-complete-extname');
const { env, settings, themes, output } = require('./configuration');
const rules = require('./rules');
const localePackPaths = require('./generateLocalePacks');

const extensionGlob = `**/*{${settings.extensions.join(',')}}*`;
const entryPath = join(settings.source_path, settings.source_entry_path);
const packPaths = sync(join(entryPath, extensionGlob));

module.exports = {
  entry: Object.assign(
    packPaths.reduce((map, entry) => {
      const localMap = map;
      const namespace = relative(join(entryPath), dirname(entry));
      localMap[join(namespace, basename(entry, extname(entry)))] = resolve(entry);
      return localMap;
    }, {}),
    localePackPaths.reduce((map, entry) => {
      const localMap = map;
      localMap[basename(entry, extname(entry, extname(entry)))] = resolve(entry);
      return localMap;
    }, {}),
    Object.keys(themes).reduce((themePaths, name) => {
      themePaths[name] = resolve(join(settings.source_path, themes[name]));
      return themePaths;
    }, {}),
  ),

  output: {
    filename: 'js/[name]-[chunkhash].js',
    chunkFilename: 'js/[name]-[chunkhash].chunk.js',
    hotUpdateChunkFilename: 'js/[id]-[hash].hot-update.js',
    hashFunction: 'sha256',
    path: output.path,
    publicPath: output.publicPath,
  },

  optimization: {
    runtimeChunk: {
      name: 'common',
    },
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        default: false,
        vendors: false,
        common: {
          name: 'common',
          chunks: 'all',
          minChunks: 2,
          minSize: 0,
          test: /^(?!.*[\\\/]node_modules[\\\/]react-intl[\\\/]).+$/,
        },
      },
    },
    occurrenceOrder: true,
  },

  module: {
    rules: Object.keys(rules).map(key => rules[key]),
  },

  plugins: [

    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ $: "jquery", jQuery: "jquery" }),

    new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(env))),
    new webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(
      /^history\//, (resource) => {
        // temporary fix for https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/5576
        // to reduce bundle size
        resource.request = resource.request.replace(/^history/, 'history/es');
      },
    ),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: 'css/[name]-[contenthash:8].css',
      chunkFilename: 'css/[name]-[contenthash:8].chunk.css',
    }),
    new AssetsManifestPlugin({
      integrity: true,
      integrityHashes: ['sha256'],
      entrypoints: true,
      writeToDisk: true,
      publicPath: true,
    }),
  ],

  resolve: {
    extensions: settings.extensions,
    modules: [
      resolve(settings.source_path),
      'node_modules',
    ],
  },

  resolveLoader: {
    modules: ['node_modules'],
  },

  node: {
    // Called by http-link-header in an API we never use, increases
    // bundle size unnecessarily
    Buffer: false,
  },
};
```

Comment: Have you tried running `bin/rails webpacker:install`.  This should setup webpack properly.

Comment: See here: https://blog.makersacademy.com/how-to-install-bootstrap-and-jquery-on-rails-6-da6e810c1b87 just use the jquery part and ignore the bootstrap & popper libraries.

Comment: Thanks, but that must be for a different version of Rails or Webpack, as I don't have a config/webpack/environment.js file in my install. I do have the javascript/packs/application.js file.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly add JQuery if don't have it in your `package.json`

```
yarn add jquery
```

As I see Mastodon have [webpack](https://github.com/mastodon/mastodon/blob/a5a00d7f7adff5e0afbd23ac1e1b16120137509a/package.json#L130)

You can use it to install JQuery in the project

For this purpose you can add changes to [`config/webpack/shared.js`](https://github.com/mastodon/mastodon/blob/a5a00d7f7adff5e0afbd23ac1e1b16120137509a/config/webpack/shared.js) or [`config/webpack/configuration.js`](https://github.com/mastodon/mastodon/blob/a5a00d7f7adff5e0afbd23ac1e1b16120137509a/config/webpack/configuration.js)

Probably first file is better. Because [plugins are installed](https://github.com/mastodon/mastodon/blob/a5a00d7f7adff5e0afbd23ac1e1b16120137509a/config/webpack/shared.js#L69-L89) there and [webpack importing](https://github.com/mastodon/mastodon/blob/a5a00d7f7adff5e0afbd23ac1e1b16120137509a/config/webpack/shared.js#L3) is already present

But you can use second file too as you wish

Finally you need to add to `plugins` array such element

```js
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ $: "jquery", jQuery: "jquery" })
```

Comment: Thanks! I added the `new webpack.ProvidePlugin` line in shared.js (see above)and recompiled, etc., but still no jQuery loading.

Comment: Thanks again! No compile errors at all. Where would I use "jquery/src/jquery" ? I also tried `new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ 'window.jQuery': 'jquery', 'window.$': 'jquery', }`

Comment: Do I really need to import in webpack? Can I add a link in the header or footer?, i.e. `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: What file would I add the script link to?

Comment: in `app/views/layouts/application.html.haml` I added `= javascript_pack_tag 'jquery-min'` to load `app/javascript/packs/jquery-min.js` but no luck.