# Adding jQuery to Rails 6 in Mastodon

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, mastodon

I gave up trying to add jQuery to Mastodon 4.0.2 via Webpacker [How do I add jQuery to Mastodon 4.02 (using Rails 6 and Webpacker 4)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75178270/how-do-i-add-jquery-to-mastodon-4-02-using-rails-6-and-webpacker-4)

So now I want to simply add a link to a jQuery CDN in the Mastodon header file `application.html.haml`.

I add

`= javascript_pack_tag "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"`

to `application.html.haml` and then run

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake tmp:cache:clear
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails assets:generate_static_pages
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails assets:precompile
```

and then exit from the root account and run

`systemctl restart mastodon-*`

*but Mastodon crashes with the app's generic error screen.*

**Edit 2/1/23**

Using

`%script src: "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"`

also crashes Mastodon.

**Questions:**

**• How can I simply add a lnk to the jQuery CDN in the header of Mastodon?**

*Edit 2/7/23 alex's solution to edit the content_security_policy.rb to use a CDN and avoid CSP issues works*

*Edit 2/6/23 alex points out that the CDN will be blocked due to CSP headers (you could add an exception in Nginx, but that's for another question); the best solution is to use alex's Sprockets answer below.*

**• Where are the error logs that would show me more info on the crash?**

*Edit 2/6/23 The most relevant logs are viewed by running*
`journalctl -f -u mastodon-web`

*which outputs:*

> Feb 06 15:12:28 ExampleMastodon bundle[9057]:
> [44fb4365-61e3-4bbb-b495-704b84c0ba06] ActionView::Template::Error
> (Inconsistent indentation: 1 tab used for indentation, but the rest of
> the document was indented using 2 spaces.)
>
> Feb 06 15:12:28 ExampleMastodon bundle[9057]:
> [44fb4365-61e3-4bbb-b495-704b84c0ba06] 32:     = javascript_pack_tag
> "locale_#{I18n.locale}", crossorigin: 'anonymous
>
> Feb 06 15:12:28 ExampleMastodon bundle[9057]:
> [44fb4365-61e3-4bbb-b495-704b84c0ba06] 33:         =
> javascript_include_tag "jquery"
>
> Feb 06 15:12:28 ExampleMastodon bundle[9057]:
> [44fb4365-61e3-4bbb-b495-704b84c0ba06] 34:     = csrf_meta_tags
>
> Feb 06 15:12:28 ExampleMastodon bundle[9057]:
> [44fb4365-61e3-4bbb-b495-704b84c0ba06] 35:     %meta{ name:
> 'style-nonce', content: request.content_security_policy_nonce }
>
> Feb 06 15:12:28 ExampleMastodon bundle[9057]:
> [44fb4365-61e3-4bbb-b495-704b84c0ba06] 36:
>
> Feb 06 15:12:28 ExampleMastodon bundle[9057]:
> [44fb4365-61e3-4bbb-b495-704b84c0ba06] 37:     = stylesheet_link_tag
> '/inert.css', skip_pipeline: true, media: 'all', id: 'inert-style'
>
> Feb 06 15:12:28 ExampleMastodon bundle[9057]:
> [44fb4365-61e3-4bbb-b495-704b84c0ba06] 38:     = stylesheet_link_tag
> custom_css_path, skip_pipeline: true, host: root_url, media: 'all'
>
> Feb 06 15:12:28 ExampleMastodon bundle[9057]:
> [44fb4365-61e3-4bbb-b495-704b84c0ba06]
>
> Feb 06 15:12:28 ExampleMastodon bundle[9057]:
> [44fb4365-61e3-4bbb-b495-704b84c0ba06]
> app/views/layouts/application.html.haml:35

**which shows the cause of the crash: "Inconsistent indentation"**

**Arrgg...**

**Fixed that and it works.**

---

This is `application.html.haml` at Github: https://github.com/mastodon/mastodon/blob/a5a00d7f7adff5e0afbd23ac1e1b16120137509a/app/views/layouts/application.html.haml

```
!!! 5
%html{ lang: I18n.locale }
  %head
    %meta{ charset: 'utf-8' }/
    %meta{ name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' }/

    - if cdn_host?
      %link{ rel: 'dns-prefetch', href: cdn_host }/
      %meta{ name: 'cdn-host', content: cdn_host }/

    - if storage_host?
      %link{ rel: 'dns-prefetch', href: storage_host }/

    %link{ rel: 'icon', href: '/favicon.ico', type: 'image/x-icon' }/

    - %w(16 32 48).each do |size|
      %link{ rel: 'icon', sizes: "#{size}x#{size}", href: asset_pack_path("media/icons/favicon-#{size}x#{size}.png"), type: 'image/png' }/

    - %w(57 60 72 76 114 120 144 152 167 180 1024).each do |size|
      %link{ rel: 'apple-touch-icon', sizes: "#{size}x#{size}", href: asset_pack_path("media/icons/apple-touch-icon-#{size}x#{size}.png") }/

    %link{ rel: 'mask-icon', href: asset_pack_path('media/images/logo-symbol-icon.svg'), color: '#6364FF' }/
    %link{ rel: 'manifest', href: manifest_path(format: :json) }/
    %meta{ name: 'theme-color', content: '#191b22' }/
    %meta{ name: 'apple-mobile-web-app-capable', content: 'yes' }/

    %title= content_for?(:page_title) ? safe_join([yield(:page_title).chomp.html_safe, title], ' - ') : title

    = stylesheet_pack_tag 'common', media: 'all', crossorigin: 'anonymous'
    = stylesheet_pack_tag current_theme, media: 'all', crossorigin: 'anonymous'
    = javascript_pack_tag 'common', crossorigin: 'anonymous'
    = javascript_pack_tag "locale_#{I18n.locale}", crossorigin: 'anonymous'
    = csrf_meta_tags
    %meta{ name: 'style-nonce', content: request.content_security_policy_nonce }

    = stylesheet_link_tag '/inert.css', skip_pipeline: true, media: 'all', id: 'inert-style'
    = stylesheet_link_tag custom_css_path, skip_pipeline: true, host: root_url, media: 'all'

    = yield :header_tags

  %body{ class: body_classes }
    = content_for?(:content) ? yield(:content) : yield

    .logo-resources{ 'tabindex' => '-1', 'inert' => true, 'aria-hidden' => true }
      = render_symbol :icon
      = render_symbol :wordmark
```

Comment: To just link to an external script just use `%script src: "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.6.min.js"` instead of the rails helpers. But `code.jquery.com` is not intended to be used as a CDN.

Comment: Thanks, but no luck; I don't know where to add `%script src: "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"`. I tried after the `%title` line, after the last `= javascript_pack_tag` and right before `%body` and I get the same Mastodon error page for any of those. I cleared cache, recompiled, restarted Mastodon, cleared CloudFlare, etc.

Comment: @max Hi Max, thanks for the earlier help; would you have some new ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Managed to get mastodon running in vagrant in development mode, but it should be the same in production, you just have to precompile and restart.

---

### Webpack

```bash
$ yarn add jquery
Done in 999.72s # <= at least it worked on the first try
```

Add it to plugins:
*https://github.com/mastodon/mastodon/blob/v4.0.2/config/webpack/shared.js#L69*

```js
// config/webpack/shared.js

plugins: [
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery',
  }),
  ...
```

*https://webpack.js.org/plugins/provide-plugin/#usage-jquery*

That means you automatically have `$` and `jQuery` in modules. A `console.log($);` in [application.js](https://github.com/mastodon/mastodon/blob/v4.0.2/app/javascript/packs/application.js#L4) gives me this:

```bash
ƒ jQuery(selector, context) {                                 application.js?2e28:4 
      // The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'
      // Need init if jQuery is called (just allow error to be thrown if not included)
      re…
```

---

You can try to add *jquery* to window if you want:

```
// app/javascript/application.js

window.$ = window.jQuery = jQuery;
//                         ^ this is automatically given by wepback.ProvidePlugin
```

Now you have `$` and `jQuery` outside of the modules:

```js
// app/views/layouts/application.html.haml

:javascript
  console.log($) // works in development
```

I think, it will fail in production, because of CSP policy, so no inline scripts.

---

### CDN

```rb
# app/views/layouts/application.html.haml

= javascript_include_tag "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.3/dist/jquery.min.js"

or

%script{ src: "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.3/dist/jquery.min.js" }
```

Network tab shows the reason it's not working:

```
jquery.min.js          (blocked:csp)        script
```

Content security policy is configured not to accept scripts from outside hosts and *nonce* is only set for styles:

*https://github.com/mastodon/mastodon/blob/v4.0.2/config/initializers/content_security_policy.rb*

You're looking for `script_src` config, it's in a few places there, I think updating this [section](https://github.com/mastodon/mastodon/blob/v4.0.2/config/initializers/content_security_policy.rb#L30-L42) should be enough:

```rb
if Rails.env.development?
  webpacker_urls = %w(ws http).map { |protocol| "#{protocol}#{Webpacker.dev_server.https? ? 's' : ''}://#{Webpacker.dev_server.host_with_port}" }

  p.connect_src :self, :data, :blob, assets_host, media_host, Rails.configuration.x.streaming_api_base_url, *webpacker_urls

  p.script_src  :self, :unsafe_inline, :unsafe_eval, assets_host, host_to_url("cdn.jsdelivr.net")
  # this one worked for me                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

  p.child_src   :self, :blob, assets_host
  p.worker_src  :self, :blob, assets_host
else
  p.connect_src :self, :data, :blob, assets_host, media_host, Rails.configuration.x.streaming_api_base_url

  p.script_src  :self, assets_host, "'wasm-unsafe-eval'", host_to_url("cdn.jsdelivr.net")
  # this one should work for you                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

  p.child_src   :self, :blob, assets_host
  p.worker_src  :self, :blob, assets_host
end
```

Home page is `explore` if you click on it in Network tab, you can see response headers:

```bash
# just showing the relevant part
Content-Security-Policy:
# this is present only in development, that means no inline scripts in production
#                   vvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
  script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' http://mastodon.local http://cdn.jsdelivr.net;
# ^^^^^^^^^^                                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

*https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP*
*https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/ContentSecurityPolicy.html*

---

### Sprockets

Download *jquery* to `vendor/assets/javascripts/jquery.js` and add it to be precompiled:

```rb
# config/initializers/assets.rb

Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += ["jquery.js"]
```

Now you don't need to mess with CSP:

```rb
# app/views/layouts/application.html.haml

= javascript_include_tag "jquery"
```

---

### In production

To double check, `nginx.conf` should be configured to serve assets from `public/assets`:
*https://github.com/mastodon/mastodon/blob/v4.0.2/dist/nginx.conf#L67*

Logger is set to `STDOUT`:
*https://github.com/mastodon/mastodon/blob/v4.0.2/config/environments/production.rb#L26*

Depending on the system and config values, finding the logs is the game of gofish. First thing it says `journalctl -u mastodon-web` to see the logs:

```bash
root@mastodon:~$ journalctl -u mastodon-web
No journal files were found.
-- No entries --

# nothing ever works the first time

root@mastodon:~$ systemctl restart systemd-journald
root@mastodon:~$ systemctl restart mastodon-web.service
root@mastodon:~$ journalctl -f -u mastodon-web
-- Logs begin at Mon 2023-02-06 11:01:52 UTC. --
Feb 06 11:05:29 mastodon systemd[1]: Started mastodon-web.
Feb 06 11:05:30 mastodon bundle[10473]: [10473] Puma starting in cluster mode...
Feb 06 11:05:30 mastodon bundle[10473]: [10473] * Puma version: 5.6.5 (ruby 3.0.4-p208) ("Birdie's Version")
# ...
# refresh the page after puma boots all the way, you should get something here
```

```bash
# in case that ^ didn't help, try this:
tail -f /var/log/syslog
```

---

I will need to see the error that you're getting to help any further.

```bash
mastodon@mastodon:~/live$ RAILS_ENV=production bin/rails assets:precompile
yarn install v1.22.19
Done in 2.50s.
INFO -- : Writing /home/mastodon/live/public/assets/jquery-6c97f936439a920f7055f372924fa39fb6acaec5a89af8467f0847ebdbe047ee.js
INFO -- : Writing /home/mastodon/live/public/assets/jquery-6c97f936439a920f7055f372924fa39fb6acaec5a89af8467f0847ebdbe047ee.js.gz
```

```bash
root@mastodon:~$ systemctl restart mastodon-web.service
```

```bash
# journalctl -f -u mastodon-web

method=GET path=/explore format=html controller=HomeController action=index status=200 duration=424.95 view=364.50 db=40.52
                                                                            ^^^^^^^^^^
```

```bash
# tail -f /var/log/nginx/access.log

"GET /assets/jquery-6c9...47ee.js HTTP/2.0" 200 31123
             ^^^^^^                         ^^^
```

Comment: Thanks for all the examples! I can see more what was wrong. I'll try the Sprockets example.

Comment: Wow, this is aggravating :( Trying the Sprockets example, I now get this compile info output `INFO -- : Writing /home/mastodon/live/public/assets/jquery....' `after running `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails assets:precompile`, and then after `systemctl restart mastodon-*`, I still get a 500 server error, while `systemctl status mastodon-*` shows everything running OK.

Comment: @BlueDogRanch see update. let me know what error you're getting.

Comment: Thanks for your help! The issue was my bad indentation, which I thought I had fixed :( Your CDN answers points out why that won't work due to CSP; I didn't try Webpack, due to CSP, as you said. nginx.conf is configured to serve assets, so your Sprockets answer works fine.

Comment: BTW, which docs did you follow to install Mastodon locally under vagrant? The ones I've found are rather opaque and assume a lot of knowledge.

Comment: @BlueDogRanch https://docs.joinmastodon.org/dev/setup/#vagrant I didn't use `vagrant-hostsupdater` it was causing issues for me. `sudo apt install vagrant virtualbox` and i had to `vagrant up` twice. you better off following a manual install tbh.

Comment: Thanks again, I tried your CDN solution and it works by editing the content_security_policy.rb file